# is $\cos x < \cos (\sin x)$ in $(0,\pi/2)$?

Tags: calculus

i need to quickly verify if $\cos x < \cos(\sin x)$ in $(0,\pi/2)$

i dont have any solid ground to prove it except by some trivil way?can anyone show a concrete way to check it?

Answer (score 8):

True: $x > \sin x \to \cos (x) < \cos (\sin x)$

Comment: why did u reverse the inequality?

Comment: @ketan: Cosine is decreasing on this interval.

Comment: Personal preference here, but shouldn't that $\rightarrow$ be a $\implies$ (`\implies`)?

Comment: @rubik they mean the same thing

Comment: @DanZimm Not always, and I think the latter is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

we can use the following two facts:(a) $\cos(x)$ is decreasing on $[0. \pi/2],$
(b) $ \sin x < x \text{ for } 0 < x \le \pi/2$ this means $$\cos x  < \cos (\sin x), 0 < x \le \pi/2.$$

p.s. in fact the inequality is true for all $x$ except for integer multiples of $2\pi$ where the equality holds.

Comment: Acctually, $x \ge \sin(x)$ for $x \ge 0$.

Comment: @Galc127, thanks. i have edited my post.

Comment: abel, I meant that (b) should be edited.

Comment: @Galc127, now (b) reads, $\sin x < x$ for $0 < x \le \pi/2.$

Comment: Which is correct, but could be edited and written as $x \ge \sin(x)$ for $x \ge 0$.

Comment: @Galc127, why? i don't want equality there.

Comment: So, $x>\sin(x)$ for $x>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Let $f(x) = x - \sin(x)$. We'll just need it on $]0,\frac{\pi}{2}[$

$f'(x) = 1 - \cos(x)$, but we know that $\cos(x) < 1$ holds on $]0,\frac{\pi}{2}[$. Hence, $f'(x) > 0$ on $]0,\frac{\pi}{2}[$. So, $f$ is increasing strictly on $]0,\frac{\pi}{2}[$. But $f(0) = 0$. Thus $f(x) > 0$ on $]0,\frac{\pi}{2}[$. In other words, $x > \sin(x)$ on $]0,\frac{\pi}{2}[$.

However, $\cos$ is decreasing strictly on $]0,\frac{\pi}{2}[$; hence $\cos(x) < \cos(\sin(x))$ on $]0,\frac{\pi}{2}[$

Answer (score 1):

$ \cos x $ decreases in the interval $ 0 < x < \pi/2 $ with derivative sign -\sin x <0,

*and* $ \sin x $ increases in the interval $ 0 < x < \pi/2, $ having derivative signs > 0.

For the given combined function derivative is $ -\sin (\sin x) \cos x $ which has

reduced magnitude with a negative sign, reduces faster than $ \cos x. $

So given inequality holds good.

Answer (score 1):

Use the facts:-
(**1**)cosine is a decreasing function
(**2**) sin(x)=x=0 at x=0
(**3**)cos(x)<1 in (0,π/2)
Since cos x and 1 are derivative of sin x and x respectively,it implies that in interval [0,π/2], x grows faster than sin(x) and is hence always greater than sin(x) which means ***cos(sin(x))>cos(x)*.**

Answer (score 1):

Observe,

For all $x_0, x_1 \in (0, \pi /2 ) $ 
$$
x_0 < x_1\implies cos(x_0) > cos(x_1)
$$

Next note that for any $x \in (0, \pi /2) $
$$ x < sin(x)  \implies cos(x) > cos(sin(x)) $$

So   $cos(x) > cos(sin(x)) $, while $x \in (0, \pi /2)$.